# Не работает админка в WP

Tags: wordpress, кодировка, denwer

кУ меня локальный сервер, после переустановки денвера (из за проблем с mySQL) перестала работать админка WP, просто пустое окно, нет не одного символа, до переустановки денвера выводила следующее сообщение (и админка и сайт)

> РџРѕС…РѕР¶Рµ, РІ РІР°С€РµР№ РєРѕРЅС„РёРіСѓСЂР°С†РёРё PHP РѕС‚СЃСѓС‚СЃС‚РІСѓРµС‚ СЂР°СЃС€РёСЂРµРЅРёРµ MySQL, РЅРµРѕР±С…РѕРґРёРјРѕРµ РґР»СЏ СЂР°Р±РѕС‚С‹ WordPress

После дешифрации:

> Похоже, в вашей конфигурации PHP отсутствует расширение MySQL, необходимое для работы WordPress

Answer (score 1):

Не работает потому что в php-extensions не стоит нужное расширение. Должны быть галочки напротив MySql и MySqli

Answer (score 0):

Сначало установите кодировку сайта по умолчанию, что бы понять причину проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы понять, что от вас хочет WP, положите в корень папки сайта файл `.htaccess` или допишите в существующий строчку `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`. Это хотя бы сделает сообщение читабельным. Далее пляшем исходя из его смысла.

Answer (score 0):

сначала надо сделать кодировку utf-8, затем сообщение можно будет расрифровать и понять проблему, скорее всего не стоит нужное расширение вот и все